# How to validate if list is empty in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

File Name: BillToparty.jsp
Problem: if `chargelist(BilltoParty)` is empty, then we need to display one alert.

```
<c:forEach items="${chargeList}" var="charge" varStatus="count">
    <td class="billToParty billingCharge${count.index}">
        <c:if test="${not empty charge.arBillToParty}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${charge.arBillToParty eq 'A'}">
                    <c:set value="${charge.arBillToParty}" var="Agent"/>
                    <c:set var="agentTotalAmount" value="${agentTotalAmount + charge.rolledupCharges + charge.adjustmentAmount}" />
                    Agent
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${charge.arBillToParty eq 'F'}">
                    <c:set value="${charge.arBillToParty}" var="Forwarder"/>
                    <c:set var="forwarderTotalAmount" value="${forwarderTotalAmount + charge.rolledupCharges + charge.adjustmentAmount}" />
                    Forwarder
                    <input type="hidden" id="fwdValidate" value="${charge.arBillToParty}">
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </c:if>
    </td>
</c:forEach>
<input type="button" class="button-style1" value="Post" id="Post" onclick="postcheck();"/>
```

File name: BilltoParty.js
Here I am validated.

```
function postcheck() {
   var flag = true;
   if ($(".billToParty").val() === "") {
       $.prompt("Please ensure all charge items have a bill to party");
       flag = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if list is empty like

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <c:if test="${empty yourList}">
```

Another way of doing it to check the size. But above approach is concise and readable

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
   <c:if test="${fn:length(yourList) > 0}">
```

**Update:-** looks like you want to check it in javascript

```
function postcheck() {
var flag=true;
   if ($("billToParty").text().trim()=="") {
              $.prompt("Please ensure all charge items have a bill to party");
              flag = false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: ok ...if list is empty we need to display one alert . how to do ?while clicking post button . we need to check billtoparty is empty .if empty we display above alert

Comment: its not working ....note this    <td class="billToParty billingCharge${count.index}">    it  have more than one rows.so until count size it needs to check

Comment: billToParty is classname.we retrieve class name values using dot operator.if ($(".billToParty").text().trim()=="") {
              $.prompt("Please ensure all charge items have a bill to party");
              flag = false;
   }